# Required Meta Data Validation is not working on Partial Views

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I have the following Main view inside my asp.net mvc-4:-

```
@model TMS.ViewModels.SwitchJoin

@Ajax.ActionLink("Add Port Info", "CreatePort","Switch",
    new { switchid = Model.Switch.SwitchID },
    new AjaxOptions {
 InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
 UpdateTargetId = "AssignPort"  ,
 LoadingElementId = "progress"


}
)
</p>
//code goes here


@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

And the following two partial view;-

```
@model TMS.Models.TMSSwitchPort



@using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreatePort", "Switch", new AjaxOptions

{
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter,
    UpdateTargetId = "Porttable",
    LoadingElementId = "loadingimag",
    HttpMethod= "POST",
    OnSuccess="submitform"
}))
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
 @Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.SwitchID)
@Html.Partial("_CreateOrEditPort", Model)
 <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary"/>
}
```

&&&

```
@model TMS.Models.TMSSwitchPort
 @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div>
<span class="f">Device Tag</span> 

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Technology.Tag)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Technology.Tag)                                              


 <span class="f"> Port Number</span>       
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PortNumber)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PortNumber)                                              



</div>
```

And I have the following Meta type Model class:-

```
    public class TMSSwitchPort_Validation
    {

        [Required]

        public string PortNumber { get; set; }


    }
}
```

But on the __CreateOrEditPort partial view the required validation will not fire? Can anyone advice please?

Comment: The Required attribute is set in class TMSSwitchPort_Validation, but in your partial view you are referencing TMS.Models.TMSSwitchPort, have you maybe reference the wrong class or are we missing the connection between TMSSwitchPort_Validation and TMS.Models.TMSSwitchPort?

Comment: no i have defined :- MetadataType(typeof(TMSSwitchPort_Validation))]
    [Bind(Include = "PortNumber,SwitchID,TechnologyID")]
    public partial class TMSSwitchPort 
    {

Answer (score 0):

Answer @develiper10214 is right but you also write about MetaType model class. I quess, are you want MetadataType class for your class.

If yes. You need to watch a few rules.

1. Your class and Metadata class need to in the same namespace (if you use this for metadata in EF database first and partial model class).
2. You need to "tell" your class than you use a metadata class.
3. Fields in class and metadata class need to be the same.

Example:

```
namespace TMS.Models
{
   public partial class TMSSwitchPort
   {
        public string PortNumber { get; set; }
   }
}
```

Another class:

```
namespace TMS.Models
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(TMSSwitchPortMetadata))]
    public partial class TMSSwitchPort
    {
        //Nothing
    }

    public class TMSSwitchPortMetadata
    {
        [Required]
        public string PortNumber { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: i already did this the TMSSwitchPortMetadata is a MetadataType class for the TMSSwitchPort. what you include is eactly what i am currently have..